# How to convert GMT date to UNIX time in golang?

Tags: go, time, epoch

I need to convert a GMT date like (`Mon, 23 Dec 2019 18:52:45 GMT`) to time.Time.Unix in Go

I've tried to parse it before and then convert it to Unix format. But it's not so clean what are the predefined layouts in time.Parse
https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of the date is `RFC1123`. Parse it with `time.Parse()` then convert it to Unix with `time.Time.Unix()`.

```
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Mon, 23 Dec 2019 18:52:45 GMT")
tUnix:= t.Unix()
fmt.Printf("%s in Unix is %d",t,tUnix)
// Output: 2019-12-23 18:52:45 +0000 GMT in Unix is 1577127165
```

[Try it online](https://play.golang.org/p/CYVDEq_Zy72)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like [time.RFC1123](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants). If not, refer to the same section to create your own layout reference string.